# How to create a proper multi-page structure with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to create a multiple page jQuery Mobile application and don't have any idea how to do that in a proper way.

Is is better to go for a single HTML file for each page or better putting all pages in one single file? How about changing pages and reacting to events like initializing, stopping, starting, coming back to pages, etc.?

I'd like to know the perfect way to build the page change with all the events in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application, you can either put all pages together or separate them. All Jquery transaction work with both methods.

Read more about this subject here: [Pages](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/pages/)